# Bootstrap Column is not expanding vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:red;">
              dfsasfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

[PLUNK to edit](https://plnkr.co/edit/7o0Jzl7VYA1Dm04nUKCw?p=preview)

This is probably something very obvious, but I thought bootstrap columns expanded vertically with content. Mine do not.

Bonus question: Was it always default behavior for bootstrap to indent "container" - how do I avoid this?

Comment: CSS : Try to use white-space: normal;

Comment: Bonus answer: Yes, it's bootstrap's default behavior. It adds a 15px padding to both left and right sides. To avoid it, you can override the CSS in your own stylesheet by using `.container{padding-left:0; padding-right:0;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's bootstrap normal behavior, because `col-*-*`  is set `float:left`, so you need to use `word-wrap:break-word`, because you don't have spaces in your text.

To avoid the *indent* you mentioned (the default `padding` that bootstrap add to `.container`), you can reset by set `.container {padding:0}`

```css
.col-xs-12 {
  background:red; /* demo */
  word-wrap: break-word
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      dfsasfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdfsasfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdfsasfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdfsasfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdfsasfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdfsasfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdfsasfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdfsasfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdfsasfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdfsasfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdfsasfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solves my problem - I was over-thinking because I didn't even consider the spacing issue. Will come back to accept answer when timer expires, ty.